# VGA driver reference

Tags: c, vga

Where can i find information on writing a vga driver?
The target platform is pic24 and i'm using c.

I sorted out the timing, but the implementation on how to display the data is a questionmark for me.

Comment: VGA driver for which OS?

Comment: A couple of links: http://wiki.osdev.org/VGA_Hardware, http://wiki.osdev.org/VGA_Resources.

Comment: I guess these links would help you make a VGA driver for yourself. This is a ping pong video game project on the PIC platform. It pretty much covers the VGA part.
http://www.rickard.gunee.com/projects/
http://hyvatti.iki.fi/~jaakko/pic/pong/pong_675.asm
http://dt.prohosting.com/pic/pong_src.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back in the early 90's the definitive reference was **Richard Ferraro's Programmer's Guide to the EGA, VGA, and Super VGA Cards**.  The book has very detailed information regarding the card registers, with it you could program even non-standard display modes such as ModeX (320-240x256-4pages) and its derivatives. (there's no reference to such modes, at least in the edition I own, but you can play with the registers and come up with interesting, custom display modes).  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please see http://www.pyroelectro.com/projects/vga_test_box/software.html for more details
and http://www.pyroelectro.com/projects/vga_test_box/software/vga-test.asm has the source code listing ...the project is based on PIC18 hope u can change it for PIC24...it displays triangle, square, circle to a VGA display.